# Comparing button properties colours

Tags: c#

I have this code

```
public void Comparing()
{
    if (button1.BackColor = Color.Red && button13.BackColor = Color.Black)
    {
        button13.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

So i think you understood what i want to do. If button1 is red and button13 is black, make button13 green. And this doesn't work. what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `if` statement you should use [`==`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) to compare, not `=` which is an assignment.

Comment: well that was embarassing.. thank you for saving me from losing another half an hour